# Glass BSDF doesn't appear correctly

Tags: eevee-render-engine, glass

I am having trouble creating two glass spheres next to each other with proper refraction and transparency:

[image]

[image]

However, I end up with either an opaque object (back sphere, when blend mode is opaque), or a glitchy transparency (front sphere, blend mode=alpha blend). I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I just need to make multiple spheres refracting through each other -- how do I achieve this?

Comment: Glass is limited in eevee - enable "backface culling" or disable "show backface" (alpha-blend).

Comment: @ChristopherBennett would it be better to switch to cycles?

Comment: Cycles is much better for (realistic) glass and transparency, though the tradeoff is much longer render times.